# Error deploying flows: Required field is missing: actionType

Tags: deployment, visual-workflow

I need to fetch components from sandbox and deploy them back to sandbox after a refresh.  First I tried with Eclipse force plugin: [Restoring sandbox components](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/273402/restoring-sandbox-components])[1](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/273402/restoring-sandbox-components)

I can fetch all needed components, but when I try to deploy a custom flow I get error:

```
Required field is missing: actionType
```

I tried with VSCode and Salesforce extension package (deploy source to org) and got same error:

```
"resource": "/c:/Users/..../..../workspace/SF2BOIntegration/force-app/main/default/flows/Create_BO_Installation.flow-meta.xml",
"owner": "deploy-errors",
"severity": 8,
"message": "Required field is missing: actionType (24:18)",
"source": "Flow",
```

I tried different API versions in package.xml (43,46) but deploy always fails.

There is a field actionType in XML file for the flow:

```
<actionCalls>
<name>Installation_Validation</name>
<label>Installation Validation</label>
<locationX>2037</locationX>
<locationY>4116</locationY>
<actionName>01pO0000000OnmzNotFound</actionName>
<actionType xsi:nil="true"/>
```

What is this field good for and how can I fix this error?

Regards

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The [Metadata API reference](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.218.0.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_visual_workflow.htm) shows that `actionType` is a required field on the `FlowActionCall` sub-object.

It's not easy to see off the bat how your metadata got into a state where it's not deployable, but there's a few possibilities I know of.

- If your real Flow uses an `actionType` like `contactRequestAction`, available starting in API 45, and you pulled the metadata using API 44 or earlier, you may get back metadata that's non-deployable, even if you update the API version for the deployment. Try re-pulling at API 46 and see if the output is different.
- If your Flow is not currently functional in the source org, it may not be deployable at all.
- If your Flow was created in a prior API version, it's conceivable (albeit not common) that you'll need to do some kind of remediation on it before deploying in current APIs.